# Site can't be reached in Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

When we check the http request with the Jmeter with 1000 user , we got the response from the server with out fail.
But if the use access the web application with the 20 users, application not loading. Some of the users get
 `this site can't be reached error`.

Can anyone suggest me for this issue.

Is there any tool is available to check UI load test like the Jmeter.

**Note**:
We had developed our application with spring

Comment: Did you just check a single HTTP request with JMeter for the 1000 user test or is it the same flow which you are using for 20 users? And out of curiosity, how are you simulating 20 users accessing the web application?

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter is the best tool for load testing. Sounds like you are having performance problem when user logins to system. In that case you should use monitoring tools to find the bottleneck. Most probably you are having very slow queries from database.

There are more then one solution in spring monitoring. I used [spring boot admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) and prometheus. Here is a [nice article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-self-hosted-monitoring) shows more tools